# Import inside CSS rule to append class on the same node level

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I have something like this

```
.my-class {
  @import url("style.less");
}
```

style.less contains

```
.second-class {
  color: red;
}
```

I get

```
.my-class .second-class {
  color: red;
}
```

I would like

```
.my-class.second-class {
  color: red;
}
```

Notice the **missing space** in the selector. Because the element I would like to style matches `.my-class` **and** `.second-class`.

I am using LESS.

How to get what I want ?

Answer (score 0):

As for as I know it is not possible in LESS. 
You should directly add **.my-class** class in **style.less** and import that file into wherever you want or make outer HTML element with **.my-class** class